# Counter en RecyclerView actualiza los TextViews de todas las filas

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter_Restaurant extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter_Restaurant.mealViewHolder> {
    private List<Meal> mealList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private int cantidadComida = 0;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter_Restaurant(Context context, List<Meal> mealList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mealList = mealList;
    }

    @Override
    public mealViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_meals_menu, parent, false);
        mealViewHolder viewHolder = new mealViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final mealViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tvMealTitulo.setText(mealList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvMealPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(mealList.get(position).getPrice()));
        holder.tvMealDescripcion.setText(mealList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.botonMasComida.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.tvCantidadComida.setText("" + (cantidadComida = cantidadComida + 1));
                //RestaurantDetalle.agregarComida(mealList.get(position).getName() + "," + mealList.get(position).getPrice());
            }
        });

        holder.botonMenosComida.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cantidadComida>0) {
                    holder.tvCantidadComida.setText("" +(cantidadComida = cantidadComida - 1));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mealList == null) ? 0 : mealList.size();
    }

    public static class mealViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CustomFontTextView tvMealTitulo;
        CustomFontTextView tvMealPrecio;
        CustomFontTextView tvMealDescripcion;
        CustomFontTextView tvCantidadComida;

        ImageButton botonMasComida;
        ImageButton botonMenosComida;

        public mealViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvMealTitulo = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMealTitulo);
            tvMealPrecio = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMealPrecio);
            tvMealDescripcion= ( CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMealDescripcion);
            tvCantidadComida = (CustomFontTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCantidadComida);
            botonMasComida = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.botonMasComida);
            botonMenosComida = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.botonMenosComida);
        }
    }
}
```

Al hacer `click` a mi botón para aumentar el contador en el `Recyclerview`, actualiza el `TextView` de las demás filas si les doy `click` en su respectivo botón.

Comment: El cambio debe ser en el elemento del objeto que alimenta el adapter no en el contenedor del RecyvlerView, agrega tu Adapter!

Comment: @Jorgesys Editado!

Comment: No tienes en tu objeto donde almacenar "cantidadcomida" ?  setCantidadComida() ???

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas el setOnClickListener de tu View en el constructor de tu clase mealViewHolder. No es una buena práctica hacerlo en el OnBindViewHolder, ya que se llama muchas veces.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Muchas gracias, es bueno saber eso! .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al dar click debes cambiar el valor en el objeto para que sea representado en la vista que muestra el `adapter`, ya que la vista obtiene el texto del objeto, si se lo agregas directamente a la vista, todos los `RecyclerView` tendrán esta propiedad.

```
//Agrega propiedad comida.  
holder.tvCantidadComida.setText(mealList.get(position).getCantidadComida());
holder.botonMasComida.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Almacena el valor en el objeto.         
        mealList.get(position).setCantidadComida(String.valueOf((cantidadComida = cantidadComida + 1)));
        // holder.tvCantidadComida.setText("" + (cantidadComida = cantidadComida + 1));
        //RestaurantDetalle.agregarComida(mealList.get(position).getName() + "," + mealList.get(position).getPrice());
    }
});
            
holder.botonMenosComida.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (cantidadComida>0) {
            //Almacena el valor en el objeto.  
            mealList.get(position).setCantidadComida(String.valueOf((cantidadComida = cantidadComida - 1)));
            //holder.tvCantidadComida.setText(""+(cantidadComida = cantidadComida - 1));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh ya entendí!!!!!! , gracias! Debe ir en el objeto Meal , saludos!

Comment: exactamente, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ